# Make image look correct in browser and print?

Tags: image, dynamic, printing, web

I dynamically create an invoice off my commerce site. At the top left of the invoice is my company logo. I need that logo to display correctly on the web, but also print sharp (I print directly off loaded page). Currently because the image is web native at 72 ppi, it does not print sharp.

How can I print the logo sharp while also displaying it correctly on the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the logo 4 times bigger.  Say the logo is 72x72 pixels.  Make the logo 288x288 and include it in your invoice html as

```
<img src="logo.gif" style="width:72px;height:72px;"/>
```

It should be downsized by the browser and printed a bit better.  If it works, and you need higher resolution, just make the logo as large as you need.

Comment: I will definitely try this and get back to you. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I finally got around to this and it worked like a charm! Thanks for the simple and effective way around my issue.